# trivially simple function and if-else statement gives syntax error unexpected token ')'

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement

I have a very simple javascript function, it should pop up an alert when a radio button is clicked.  If I click the no radio button it works, but if I click yes I get the syntax error unexpected token ')' and I cannot see why.

Code:

```
    <script>
        function check(val) {
            if (val == "Yes"){
                alert("Yes")
            }else{
                alert("No")
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: This is syntactically correct. Can you post the calling code?

Comment: The error must be caused by something outside this function declaration. Check other places in your sources where this function is mentioned, presumably in `Element#addEventListener`s or in the HTML code.

Comment: I am sure you are missing some code. But dose this happen in all the browsers?

Comment: It is called by some radio buttons - I have added the code to the post

Answer (score 0):

Never mind - syntax error in the radio buttons!